# How to override root.phtml template in my custom theme for product view page

Tags: magento2, template, product-page

I'd copying **`root.phtml`** (from **`vandor/magento/module-theme/view/base/`**) in to my theme (**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/root.phtml`**).
All pages root templates  is override except product page.
I am using **Magento v 2.2.2**
The Parent theme is "blank".
I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Did you tried `setup:static-content:deploy` command? & what changes you are expecting into your product page put some hints so that you can get proper help from someone

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache, and tried setup:static-content:deploy command. but this does not give a result.
I need to override root template for rewrite doctype head and body tags. It's need for create Amp theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did the same thing and did not have a problem.  The changes applied for every page I tested.  Perhaps you have another module that is supplying an override for the product page? Or perhaps your product page layout is using some other layout that is not using root [just a crazy guess]?

Or perhaps you can update your module's di.xml to replace this default config, provided by the di.xml in magento2-base\app\etc, with an entry that point to the root.phtml in your module?

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="layoutReaderPool" xsi:type="object">pageConfigRenderPool</argument>
        <argument name="generatorPool" xsi:type="object">pageLayoutGeneratorPool</argument>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::root.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps it's override problem.